# Deploy R function with directory as argument as executable or web application

Tags: r, deployment, shiny, executable

I've written an R function (code available on demand) that improves some analysis workflows in my research group (~10 people), and now I would like to deploy it so it's easily accessible to the rest of the group. I am the only person in the group with any knowledge of R.

In a nutshell, the function does the following:

- Takes one argument, the directory in which to search for microscopy images in proprietary formats
- Asks user (with `readline()`) which channels should be analysed and what they are named
- Generate several histograms and scatter plots of intensity levels per image channel, after various normalisation steps, these are deposited in a .pdf file for each image stack
- Perform linear regression, generate a .txt file per image stack

The .pdf and .txt files get output to the directory the user specifies as the argument when running the function. I want to turn it into something somewhat more user-friendly, essentially removing the need to install R + function dependencies. For the sake of universality I would like to deploy it as a web application that takes a .zip file of the images as input, extracts them and then runs the function with that newly created directory as the argument. When it's done, it should output a .zip file of the created .pdfs and .txts. I'm not sure how feasible this is. I have looked into using Shiny for this but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to apply it as I do not have experience with it. I have experience in unix server administration and have a remote server that I can play around with.

The second option would be somewhat less universal, but it would be to deploy it as a Windows executable (I am the only person in my group not to use Windows as a daily OS, but I do have access to a Windows environment). Here, ideally the executable should ask the user to navigate to a directory, then use that directory as the argument to the function and output the generated files in said directory.

As my experience with R is limited, I cannot tell which option would be more feasible and worth it in the long run. My gut feeling says the web application would be the most flexible and user friendly, but more challenging to deploy. Are either of my ideas implementable, and if so, what would be a good way to do so?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This should be not more than a bash script. You can run R scripts from the command line using `Rscript -e "source('myscript.R')"`. Making a small website that asks the user for input shouldn't be very hard. Otherwise, I would also have recommended Shiny. There are lots of tutorials out there.

Comment: No idea about the executable, though.

Comment: I think I'll try it with Shiny, might as well start to learn it because I reckon I'll use it more often in the future. Thanks!